# Using VBA to import Rows data to existing PowerPoint slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I was trying to figure out away to get Rows data into my existing Slides, by PowerPoint VBA command, i got this code but this is creating new slides and filling data, instead of pasting on existing slides.

````
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()


Dim OWB As New Excel.Workbook
Set OWB = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open("F:\Working\BOOK.xls") 'Change the file path here
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Set WS = OWB.Worksheets(1)
Dim str As String
Dim i, j As Integer

For i = 1 To WS.Range("A500").End(xlup).Row
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Copy
    ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste (ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1)
    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = WS.Rows(i).End(xlToRight).Column
    If LastCol = 200 Then LastCol = 1
    str = ""
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        If j <> 1 Then str = str & Chr(13)
        str = str & WS.Cells(i, j).Value
    Next
    ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = str
Next
End Sub```
````

Comment: Which existing slides?  How will you tell which slide to paste data (for example, presumably not the title slide and other non-data slides)? Is there a table on the slide already? Is there an Excel-linked table? Do you want an Excel-linked table, or just the data, or an image/bitmap of the Excel data?

Comment: @PeterT, All the slides present in my PPT file(From Slide 1 - Last slide) , Slides doesn't have any shape/Table,  They only have an Image pasted at the center